# spark local mode is not honor spark.app.id property

Tags: apache-spark

We tried to use spark local mode instead of cluster mode, but spark in local mode does not honor spark.app.id property from the spark properties file. It always use some internal `local-<timestamp>` as the app id.
We use script to manage the spark.app.id, and would like to use the spark local mode too. We need to use the spark history to inspect the spark job.

Comment: You should ask about something, but I don't see any question here.

Comment: My question is how to change spark application ID for local mode, we try to change it by setting the spark properties spark.app.id, and it does not apply to spark local mode, only works for cluster mode.

Answer (score 2):

From Spark Source you can see:

```
/**
   * A unique identifier for the Spark application.
   * Its format depends on the scheduler implementation.
   * (i.e.
   *  in case of local spark app something like 'local-1433865536131'
   *  in case of YARN something like 'application_1433865536131_34483'
   *  in case of MESOS something like 'driver-20170926223339-0001'
   * )
   */
```

And when you provide the master as `local` it will use `LocalSchedulerBackend` which initialize the app id as:

```
  private val appId = "local-" + System.currentTimeMillis
```

And when you run on cluster it will accept the `spark.app.id` and will use it, class `StandaloneSchedulerBackend` and there's logic to get it from that property.

Hope it helps you.